Visual Studio custom extension does not execute command
I am currently trying on my first custom Visual Studio 2022 Extension. In detail I want to generate a canvas which draws points based on the double values. All this happens in theory when I set in another sourcecode a breakpoint and look at an IEnumerable and check the view with the magnifying glass
I went through the tutorial I found from Microsoft and got everything setup and working to the point where a message popped up aka "Hello World" now I implemented my logic but I can't get it to work and I don't know why.
The Button to call it is still here and I get no Error Message
here is my Command.cs
using Microsoft;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility.Commands;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility.Shell;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MTEnumVisualizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Command1 handler.
    /// </summary>
    [VisualStudioContribution]
    internal class Command1 : Command
    {
        private readonly TraceSource logger;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Command1"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="traceSource">Trace source instance to utilize.</param>
        public Command1(TraceSource traceSource)
        {
            
            this.logger = Requires.NotNull(traceSource, nameof(traceSource));
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override CommandConfiguration CommandConfiguration => new("%MTEnumVisualizer.Command1.DisplayName%")
        {
            Icon = new(ImageMoniker.KnownValues.Extension, IconSettings.IconAndText),
            Placements = [CommandPlacement.KnownPlacements.ExtensionsMenu],
        };

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            this.logger.TraceInformation("Command1 initialized.");
            return base.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            this.logger.TraceInformation("ExecuteCommandAsync started.");

            Requires.NotNull(context, nameof(context));

            // Retrieve debugger data
            var dataPoints = await GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync(context, cancellationToken);
            if (dataPoints is null || !dataPoints.Any())
            {
                this.logger.TraceInformation("No data points were retrieved from the debugger.");
                return;
            }

            // Determine the highest value and calculate canvas height
            double maxValue = dataPoints.Max();
            double canvasHeight = maxValue * 1.1;

            // Create window
            var window = new Window
            {
                Title = "Data Points Visualization",
                Width = 800,
                Height = 600
            };

            // Create canvas
            var canvas = new Canvas
            {
                Width = 800,
                Height = canvasHeight
            };

            // Draw points on the canvas
            foreach (var point in dataPoints)
            {
                var ellipse = new Ellipse
                {
                    Width = 5,
                    Height = 5,
                    Fill = Brushes.Black
                };

                Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, point * 100); // Example X-coordinate
                Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, canvasHeight - (point * 100)); // Example Y-coordinate

                canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
            }

            // Add canvas to window
            window.Content = canvas;

            // Show message
            MessageBox.Show("The window will now be displayed.");

            // Display window
            window.ShowDialog();
        }

        private async Task<IEnumerable<double>> GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // This is where the code to retrieve data points from the debugger should go
            await Task.Delay(100); // Simulates an asynchronous operation

            // Example data points
            var dataPoints = new List<double> { 1.0, 2.5, 3.8, 4.2, 5.0 };

            this.logger.TraceInformation($"Retrieved data points: {string.Join(", ", dataPoints)}");

            return dataPoints;
        }
    }
}


Due to request I highlighted the minimal Code exactly showing the dummy data and the Execute Async which seems to not go through properly
        public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.logger.TraceInformation("ExecuteCommandAsync started.");

        Requires.NotNull(context, nameof(context));

        // Retrieve debugger data
        var dataPoints = await GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync(context, cancellationToken);
        if (dataPoints is null || !dataPoints.Any())
        {
            this.logger.TraceInformation("No data points were retrieved from the debugger.");
            return;
        }

        // Determine the highest value and calculate canvas height
        double maxValue = dataPoints.Max();
        double canvasHeight = maxValue * 1.1;

        // Create window
        var window = new Window
        {
            Title = "Data Points Visualization",
            Width = 800,
            Height = 600
        };

        // Create canvas
        var canvas = new Canvas
        {
            Width = 800,
            Height = canvasHeight
        };

        // Draw points on the canvas
        foreach (var point in dataPoints)
        {
            var ellipse = new Ellipse
            {
                Width = 5,
                Height = 5,
                Fill = Brushes.Black
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, point * 100); // Example X-coordinate
            Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, canvasHeight - (point * 100)); // Example Y-coordinate

            canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
        }

        // Add canvas to window
        window.Content = canvas;

        // Show message
        MessageBox.Show("The window will now be displayed.");

        // Display window
        window.ShowDialog();
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<double>> GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // This is where the code to retrieve data points from the debugger should go
        await Task.Delay(100); // Simulates an asynchronous operation

        // Example data points
        var dataPoints = new List<double> { 1.0, 2.5, 3.8, 4.2, 5.0 };

        this.logger.TraceInformation($"Retrieved data points: {string.Join(", ", dataPoints)}");

        return dataPoints;
    }

string-ressource.json
{
  "MTEnumVisualizer.Command1.DisplayName": "IEnumerable<double> Visualizer"
}

ExtensionEntrypoint.cs
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility;

namespace MTEnumVisualizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension entrypoint for the VisualStudio.Extensibility extension.
    /// </summary>
    [VisualStudioContribution]
    internal class ExtensionEntrypoint : Extension
    {
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public override ExtensionConfiguration ExtensionConfiguration => new()
        {
            Metadata = new(
                    id: "MTEnumVisualizer.6a2dffe7-b3c6-418d-9e1d-d9aa1d933426",
                    version: this.ExtensionAssemblyVersion,
                    publisherName: "User",
                    displayName: "MTEnumVisualizer",
                    description: "Visualisierer um ENumerable<double> grafisch darzustellen"),
        };

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void InitializeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            base.InitializeServices(serviceCollection);

            // You can configure dependency injection here by adding services to the serviceCollection.
        }
    }
}

I tried to simply put a MessageBox.Show() to determine if my Code breaks at some point and my logic is just plain wrong. But it didn't pop up so my only guess would be that this block does not get called at all. I reverted it to the original state with the "Hello World" and it worked just fine

Could you please share a minimal sample to help better investigate your issue?

@DouXu-MSFT ofc I edited my original post and put the Execute Async and my dummy data below

Did you add other files or codes  except  Command.cs file. It's would be better if you can share a complete repro steps as i can't run your code at my side.

No I did not add any other files except "Command.cs". The rest was autogenerated and not touched by Visual studio: Which includes a "string-resoruces.json" and a "ExtensionEntrypoint.cs"
but just so its full and complete I will edit my post and include them

Ok, i will copy your updated files to my local and try to run this project. Will let you know if there is an update.

Any dependencies not found error in console/output? VS will not show an exception if there as error in initializing your code. Can you debug the VS within VS?

dependencies are all included and found so no this is not the issue

It sounds like your custom command isn't executing as expected in Visual Studio. Since you’ve confirmed the basic setup works (as your "Hello World" command showed up), but not the more complex code, here are a few troubleshooting tips to help you track down the issue.

Check Command Activation Conditions
Make sure that the command is active and registered correctly by verifying the Placements and any conditions under which the command should be enabled. If you’re using a button, confirm that the command handler is correctly attached to it. Try placing another message log (e.g., this.logger.TraceInformation("Command triggered");) at the beginning of ExecuteCommandAsync to see if it's even triggered.

Check CommandConfiguration
Double-check that CommandConfiguration is correctly set up with the following:


Placements: Ensure this is correctly configured so that your command button appears in the right menu or context.
Icon and DisplayName: Confirm that these are correct and don’t throw any hidden errors. You could comment out the Icon or simplify it temporarily to see if it impacts the command’s visibility or functionality.
3. Logger and TraceSource
Verify that TraceSource is correctly initialized and configured. You can add more logger.TraceInformation() calls at different points in ExecuteCommandAsync to track execution flow.

Debugging the Command Execution
You mentioned using MessageBox.Show() for debugging but not seeing anything. Add more TraceInformation or simpler logging messages to pinpoint where execution might stop:

Place a TraceInformation immediately inside ExecuteCommandAsync.
Add a MessageBox.Show() before and after await GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync(context, cancellationToken); to check if the command is reaching this part.
Verify dataPoints content after GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync returns by logging its values.
5. Simplify Canvas Creation and Window Display
Since the canvas visualization and window display code could introduce additional complexity, try commenting out that part to see if the issue lies there:
Comment out everything except the first few logger.TraceInformation() lines in ExecuteCommandAsync.
Gradually add code back, starting with creating the Window without any Canvas logic, to see if that executes correctly.
Add a basic Canvas without drawing elements, and then incrementally add back the drawing code.
6. Debugger Data Retrieval
Since your GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync method returns dummy data points, it should ideally work. However, try returning a hardcoded List directly without the await Task.Delay(100); to rule out any async-related issues.
Example for Simplification:
 private Task<IEnumerable<double>> GetDebuggerDataPointsAsync(IClientContext 
 context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var dataPoints = new List<double> { 1.0, 2.5, 3.8, 4.2, 5.0 };
     this.logger.TraceInformation($"Retrieved data points: {string.Join(", ", 
 dataPoints)}");
     return Task.FromResult(dataPoints.AsEnumerable());
 }


Debugging Extension in Experimental Instance
If you aren’t already, try debugging your extension in an Experimental Instance of Visual Studio. This lets you use breakpoints to inspect the flow and check the value of variables. Use F5 to start debugging the extension project, which should open a new instance of Visual Studio in Experimental mode where you can interact with and debug your extension.

Try Catch for Exception Handling
Wrap ExecuteCommandAsync code in a try-catch block to capture any unhandled exceptions that might be silently stopping the execution.


Example:
public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        this.logger.TraceInformation("ExecuteCommandAsync started.");

        // Your existing code...

        MessageBox.Show("Execution reached end of command.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.TraceError($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


Alternative Debugging Techniques
In cases like this, you can also debug by outputting logs to a file instead of relying solely on TraceSource. This can help to ensure that logs are recorded even if Visual Studio’s trace system doesn’t output them as expected.

By following these steps, you should be able to pinpoint where execution stops and understand why the command might not be executing fully.

I ran through the debug and with breakpoints and he just leaves after drawing the canvas. logs are not really adding anything of value. tried swapping the canvas with bitmap.. same behaviour
